# UIButton not toggling between two images Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am wanting to add sounds to my app.  I have added a UIButton with two images, soundON and soundOFF.
When I call the sound settings in the app the first time, they toggle fine with each image.
However, when I return to the sound settings a second and subsequent time, it is like the soundOff images does not disappear when the soundOn image is displayed.
Odd as the code is so short and simple.

```
func soundButton() {
    sounds = UIButton(frame : CGRect(x: 65, y: 70, width: 40, height:40))
    sounds.setImage(UIImage(named : "soundON"), for : .normal)
    sounds.setImage(UIImage(named : "soundOFF"), for : .selected)
    sounds.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
    sounds.addTarget(self, action: #selector(soundButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.soundView.addSubview(sounds)
}

@objc func soundButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    sounds.isSelected.toggle()
    isSoundOn.toggle()
}
```

I have added a video to show the issue as this will save a ton of typing.

http://www.reeflifeapps.com/soundError.mov

Any help is greatly appreciated.

update:
I had the button on a UIView that was hidden on startup of the puzzle. When the user pressed the "Sounds Settings" icon, the sound setting UIView was unhidden. I had the button on this func to unhide the sound settings. I moved it to viewDidLoad() and it fixed it.

Comment: where you called this `soundButton()`

Comment: It looks like soundButton() is called every time you open sound settings, so when you open sound settings first time it works fine but when you open it again it will add new sound Button to soundView

Comment: It seems that your sound button is created every time you show the system sound view.

Comment: show us both toggle methods  and also where you call soundButton() ?? @anbu's question is good.

Comment: @Anbu, that was it.  I had the button on a UIView that was hidden on startup of the puzzle.  When the user pressed the "Sounds Settings" icon, the sound setting UIView was unhidden.  I had the button on this func to unhide the sound settings.  I moved it to viewDidLoad() and it fixed it.  Please put that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to define a boolean variable that keeps the current state of your button. Then, you should set current image of button according to the current state of the variable.

```
var isSoundOn = false

@objc func soundButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    isSoundOn.toggle()
    if isSoundOn {
        // your logic when sound on (set button selected image, action etc)
    } else {
        // logic when sound off (set button not selected image, action etc)
    }
}
```

If you still want to use `soundButton.isSelected` as your boolean variable,do **not** define images for different states in `soundButton.setImage(yourImage, for: .selected)` and `soundButton.setImage(yourImage, for: .normal)` and define them as follows:

```
soundButton.setImage(soundButton.isSelected ? soundOnImage : soundOffImage, for: .normal)
```

One of those two approaches above can be used.

**UPDATE:**

As Lloyd Kaijzer stated, `isSoundOn = !isSoundOn` updated as `isSoundOn.toggle()`

Comment: In swift 4.2 isSoundOn = !isSoundOn can be replaced with isSoundOn.toggle()

Comment: Presetting the images (once) for `.selected` and `.normal` and changing them with `isSelected` is pretty standard practice.

Comment: Thanks, all. I have tried both the above with the same result.  The button is loaded in viewDidLoad().  The images still toggle, but on top of each other, rather than replacing each other.  That is what is so odd.  Swift 4.2, maybe I need to remove an image before displaying the second?

Comment: I know it's a well-known practice, however I have suggested to replace the current image of button since @DavidSanford says it overlays the image rather than replace it. You probably have another issue related to the code you haven't displayed here because I have tried and don't see the same problem with the code above.